# How to move slurm node from alloc state to idle state?

Tags: slurm

Currently, my cluster looks as follows

```
sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      1  alloc ip-a-b-c-d
debug*       up   infinite      7   idle <list of ips>
```

### Debug using `squeue`

The node in allocated state seems to be running bash

```
squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
                16     debug     bash   ubuntu  R      13:47      1 ip-a-b-c-d
```

Answer (score 0):

Flush out the queued bash job

```
scancel -n bash
```

Verify no queued job

```
$ squeue
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
```

Now confirm the allocated node is back to idle state

```
ubuntu:~$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      8   idle ip-a-b-c-d, ... <list of other idle ips>
```